# VueJS 3 create/pass hyperscript to template at runtime?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-render-function

I wanted to try something for performance/convenience purposes, I understand the gains will be minimal but understanding how/if/why this works would also just be helpful to learn.

I have a some custom data types (defined as classes) that are used to identify certain properties throughout my application. I want to use a static function on the type to define a display function. (stripped down) Example:

```
class Email extends String{
    static display = (value) => {
        return `<a href='mailto${value}'>${value}</a>`;
    }
}
```

Call it like you do:

```
Email.display("test@test.com");
```

And that works in the template, so long as it’s in a `v-html` attribute. This is perfectly acceptable.

It’s probably important to specify I’m working with Vue-CLI and single-file components, so all that sweet hyperscript gets created at compile time.

But it got me thinking, is there a way I can pass a freshly-created hyperscript to the template at render? Preferably in a way that works in the `{{mustache}}` if at all possible.

I tried doing it with `h` but that just displays the ol’ `[object Object]`.

```
class Email extends String{
    static display = (value) => {
        return h('a', {innerHtml: value});
    }
}
```

---

**Update: also tried**

I thought maybe going around the Vue render functions could get the job done, but they don't seem to like document fragments either.

```
static display = (value) => {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.textContent = value;
    fragment.appendChild(a);
    return fragment;
}
```

---

**Question**
Is there a way create hyperscript at runtime and utilize it in a vue template? Bonus points if it works in `{{mustache}}` and `v-html`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally component templates and render functions that use JSX or `h` (hyperscript) are mutually exclusive.

It's really possible to do this, in this case `display` is actually [functional component](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#functional-components), and it needs to be output as any other dynamic component:

```
setup() {
    const display = (props) => {
      return h(...);
    };

    return { display };
}
```

and

```
<component :is="display" :value="..."/>
```

The return of `display` is a hierarchy of vnode objects, they can't be used as is in `v-html` without being previously rendered to HTML.

Comment: So basically, create a component? Kind of defeats the purpose of the question.

Comment: You can create it with higher order function, or write helper function or component that wraps vnodes with a function, but the thing is that `display` in `<component :is="display"` is supposed to be a function that returns vnode.